# How to lock drive Icon on launcher?

Tags: icons

I unintentionally **unlocked one drive from launcher** ?
How to add again ?

Comment: I didn't find this to be helpful.Please help me is details.

Answer (score 1):

Reset the settings, open terminal <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> and run this command

```
gsettings reset com.canonical.Unity.Devices blacklist
```